# What is the reasoning behind Avshalom's name

Tags: names, tanach, king-david

Why was Avshalom named so. It's kind of ironic that his name means "my father is peace", no? Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Actually, Avshalom means "father [of] peace" (without the 'my' part). This is also how English Wikipedia's "[Absalom](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Absalom&oldid=1022945672)" gives it. "My father is peace" would better fit the name Av**i**shalom (like in "[מעכה בת אבישלום](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D)"), though אב**י**שלום could also mean "אבי (ה)שלום", again "father [of] (the) peace".

Comment: According to Hebrew Wikipedia's "[אבשלום](https://he.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&oldid=31375769#%D7%90%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%A9%D7%9D)" Avshalom/Avishalom is probably a [theophoric name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophoric_name), with the Av/Avi part referring to God.